# Music Library List App - UWP / C#

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, binding, uwp

I comment'm developing an application in C # for UWP, I am new to this and I'm willing to show the list of songs with his album and artist, I've done in a ListView with (ListView.items.add) together their properties, but this is not at all aesthetic.
Binding is possible with? Could you help me?

```
 protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        this.DataContext = this;


        StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;

        var files = await storageFolder.GetFilesAsync();


        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            var musicProperties = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();

            var Artista = musicProperties.Artist;
            if (Artista == "")
            {
                Artista = "Artista desconocido";
            }
            string fileName = file.DisplayName;

            listView.Items.Add(file.DisplayName + "-" + Artista  );

        }


    }
```

Comment: Sorry buddy but you might want to try a different translator for your question because it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I want to do is to show the variable "filename" in a textblock that is within a ListView

Comment: Ok, and what you're getting instead?

Answer (score 1):

> Binding is possible with?

Yes, binding is possible and I think binding is a better way than adding items to `ListView` in the code behind, you should be able to use `DataTemplate` to build the structure of each item and use [ObservableCollection Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection%601);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) to provide notifications when items get added, removed or refreshed.

For example here:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind MusicList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="File Name: " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding FileName}" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Artist: " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist}" />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Album: " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Album}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And you need to create a data model class for these "FileName", "Artist", and "Album" properties:

```
public class MusicLib
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Artist { get; set; }
    public string Album { get; set; }
}
```

code behind:

```
private ObservableCollection<MusicLib> MusicList = new ObservableCollection<MusicLib>();

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
}

protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    StorageFolder musicLib = KnownFolders.MusicLibrary;
    var files = await musicLib.GetFilesAsync();
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var musicProperties = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
        var artist = musicProperties.Artist;
        if (artist == "")
            artist = "Artista desconocido";
        var album = musicProperties.Album;
        if (album == "")
            album = "Unkown";
        MusicList.Add(new MusicLib { FileName = file.DisplayName, Artist = artist, Album = album });
    }
}
```

I used your method to set the empty "Artist" and "Album" properties to certain values here, but you can also use `Converter` to do this work, for the information about using `Converter`, you can refer to [IValueConverter interface](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter.aspx), there is sample in this doc.

By the way, if you want to access the Music Library in your app, you need to enable the "Music Library" capability in your "Package.appxmanifest" file.